# Sql inner join a select syntax to lambdas .join() syntax

Tags: c#, sql, syntax, lambda

I got this query :

```
select t.user
     , t.loginDate 
from t_login as t
inner join 
(
    select user, max(loginDate) as mostRecentLoginDate 
    from t_login 
    group by user
) as tt
    on t.user = tt.user 
   and t.loginDate = tt.mostRecentLoginDate ;
```

this query works great , it gives me the most recent loginDate for my user.

Now I would like to have this query in Lambdas syntax for my C# code.

Is that possible ?

EDIT :

C# code :

```
myApp.DataLayer dl = new myapp.DataLayer();
IQueryable<Logins> logins = dl.getAllLogins();

if(displayRecent)
{
    logins = logins.Where(p => p.LoginDate == logins.Where(pp => pp.User == p.User).Max(pp => pp.LoginDate));
}

foreach (Login login in logins) // here it crash with StackOverflow exception
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a test with Linq to object. It should work for Linq to SQL:

```
    public class Login { public DateTime loginDate { get; set; } public string user { get; set; } }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void foo()
    {
        var logins = new[] { 
          new Login() { loginDate = new DateTime(2013, 5, 1), user = "u1" }
        , new Login() { loginDate = new DateTime(2013, 5, 2), user = "u1" }
        , new Login() { loginDate = new DateTime(2013, 5, 3), user = "u2" }
        , new Login() { loginDate = new DateTime(2013, 5, 4), user = "u2" }

        };

        var lastLogins = logins.Where(l =>
                    l.loginDate == logins.Where(ll => ll.user == l.user)
                                         .Max(ll => ll.loginDate)
        ).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: this code cause : An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll when I enter into my foreach login in logins

Answer (score 1):

Try something along these lines:

```
var latestLogin = logins.Where(u => u.user == "userName").Max(u => u.logindate);
```